# How do you change the label on an idMSO button on the Ribbon

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

Microsoft Word 2010

From ribbon XML:

```
<button idMso="TableRowsDelete"  getScreentip="RibbonControl.Get_Screen_Tip" getLabel="RibbonControl.Get_Label" showLabel="true" size="normal"/>
```

My tab switches between 2 languages, so the label and screen tip changes for each button. For all the custom buttons I have created, I can change the labels and screen tips. However, for all the Microsoft buttons I included in my tab, the label and screen tip remains unchanged.

**Is there something special that needs to be added, so I can change these too?**

Answer (score 0):

To change the language of built-in controls, you need to make sure that the corresponding UI language is installed, e.g. using a *Language Interface Pack*.

You can then set the language by setting the following Registry entry to the respective language ID, e.g. 1033 for en-US:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\LanguageResources::UILanguage
```

For the change to take effect, Office needs to be restarted though, so you won't be able to change the language on the fly.

Comment: Sorry, not very helpful when creating a bilingual document. In previous versions of Word as well as Word 2011 for Mac, one was able to customize existing as well as custom tooltips for each button on the command bar. Looks like the removed the functionality for the ribbon UI.